# fetch all messages in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, string, core-data

So I am building a chat application in Swift 3 and recently had the issue that I want my user to be able to scroll through all messages without having to wait for the messages to be fetched (without being interrupted).

In order to accomplish that I tried to set the method which I use for fetching the previous messages to the highest number possible. Now I think that there has to be a smarter solution because a constant number would be stupid.

```
func configureComponents() {        
  let coreData = CoreDataStack.shared

  UserDefaults.standard.set(userName, forKey: "user")

  if coreData.fetch(user: userName) == nil {
    coreData.save(user: userName)
  }


  let messages = coreData.fetch(amount: 1000000, from: user)
  fillMessages(messages: messages)

}


func loadEarlierMessages() {
  let messages = coreData.fetch(amount: 1000, from: user)

  guard messages.count > 0 else {
    return
  }
  self.insertAtStart(messages: messages)
  var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
  var index = 0
  for _ in 0...messages.count-1 {
    indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: index, section: 0))
    index += 1
  }
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
      self.collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
      }, completion: nil)
  }

}
```

This is the code that I wrote.

Now the question is: **Do you know an alternative way to fetch *all messages* not just the 1000 I fetch at the moment?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming the user will only be able to see 10-15 messages at a time, it would be better to implement a page concept. The app could store 2-3 pages of messages in either scroll direction, in memory. Each page could have 15 messages in it. This way you can avoid loading so many messages and at the same time have a smooth scrolling experience. When the user scrolls the app would load more pages (relative to the current position) in the background.

Comment: Any reason not to use a FetchedResultsController / UITableView?  FRCs generally do a nice job of managing the retrievals and scrolling.

Comment: @user2773289 that might be a good solution but i am storing all messages locally any way so i could load them all at once

Comment: @DanClark well in a messenger app UITableViews aren't the best solution ;)

Comment: Just for learning purposes, was wondering why not.  I'm using one in a mapKit / tracking context where I'll get thousands of waypoints and it manages that fine even on a 5S; what is it about messenger apps that makes them impractical?